# How can I make two joined open arcs(without the horizontal line) in HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am new to canvas element in HTML, and am trying to make something like `~` using `.arc()` method.

Here's my code: (or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mj9tof6y/))

**HTML**

```
    <canvas height = "500" width = "500" id = "myCanvas"></canvas>
```

**Javascript**

```
    let canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI, true);
    ctx.arc(150, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
```

I am getting a horizontal line connecting the start and the end of the two joined semicircles. How can I remove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `moveTo` the beginning of your second arc: *cx + rad, cy*

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.lineWidth = 3;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI, true);
// move the pointer to the next drawing point without tracing anything
ctx.moveTo(150 + 50, 50);
ctx.arc(150, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas height="500" width="500" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```